# How Can I add an API Key to a JS AJAX Request?

Tags: ajax, curl

I've been accessing an API via cURL on the command line. In attempting to convert this to javascript, I've had issues.

The code below functions correctly within the command line:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Api-Key: vZKoJwFB1PTJnozKBSANADc3" "https://api.commonstandardsproject.com/api/v1/jurisdictions"
```

The following is the attempted javascript conversion:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
    }
    };
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.commonstandardsproject.com/api/v1/jurisdictions", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Api-Key", "vZKoJwFB1PTJnozKBSANADc3");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");   
xhttp.send();
```

Error messages return a basic 401 error, ostensibly indicating some issue with my input of the Api-Key. Have I made any noticeable errors? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The browser adds other headers in the request. For example the user agent string is different, gzip is enabled by default, etc. I would start looking there. Also I hope you haven’t posted here you real api key and if so, please delete it asap.

Comment: The API key's literally listed on their website. It's the sort of thing where anyone making a request uses the same one, not an individually-issued thing.